# Why isn't rendering @search working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I go to my page at `127.0.0.1/searches/new` and I click to submit, I get:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Searches#show

Missing partial searches/search with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
```

I don't understand why, since normally Rails sends the result to the `yield`, no?

In my `show.html`:

```
<%= render @search.calendars %>
```

In my controller `searches_controller.rb`:

```
def new
  @search = Search.new
end

def create
  @search = Search.create!(params[:params]) 
  redirect_to @search
end

def show
  @search= Search.find(params[:id])
end
```

In my model `searches.rb`:

```
def calendars
  @calendars ||= find_calendars
end

private

def find_calendars
  calendars = Calendar.order(:event)
  calendars = calendars.where("event like ?", "%#{keywords}%") if keywords.present?
  calendars
end
```

In my `routes.rb`:

```
resources :searches
```

Comment: Do you have a partial in a file in `app/views/searches/_search.html.erb`? That's what the error message says Rails is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The following line tries to render the model via a partial view:

```
<%= render @search.calendars %>
```

If rendering via a partial view is what you want then you have to create the file at `app/views/searches/_searches.html.erb`.

Alternatively remove the render call above and put the rendering logic within the `app/views/searches/view.html.erb` file instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you have this in your `app/view/searches/new.html.erb`:

```
<%= render @search %>
```

Above is a shorthand that, if `@search` was an instance of `Search` which it is, effectively does this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'searches/search', :locals => {:search => @search} %>
```

However, your application does not find the view partial `app/views/searches/_search.html.erb`.

What exactly did you want to be the content for this? Replace this code, or create the missing file and add content.